# reusing typescript object in an array of object

Tags: javascript, typescript

How would you type this nested array of object?

```
const myItem: Items[] = [{
    id: 1,
    text: 'hello',
    items: [{
        id: 1,
        text: 'world'
    }]
}]
```

I could do this

```
interface Item {
    id: number
    text: string
}

interface Items {
    id: number // avoid this duplication?
    text: string // avoid this duplication?
    items: Item[]
}
```

but I wish to get rid of the duplication. If the item has a lot more properties it doesn't look good.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChkHLAAmAXMiAK4YBG0+hkAHmOQM5hSgDmuAvrlyhIsRCnQQMbHAwIlyVWtGQB6FcjgA3APYlkYABbBpxSgAcANsARwwwbSAD8s-RBbtOPVeq27i+oxNzKxs7B2dCIkw2cgkMAG0AXX5BBAcOZAwATzjY6KTkAF5keLxI+WQARgAaF2ZWZAByAwgLC21G2vLo8lKXcrIqrsjGNwbGgHdtKAtiRpc+ZMWgA

Comment: Don't you just want one interface which has `items?: Item[]`? Or do you have two distinct types of objects where one has `items` the other doesn't?

Comment: @VLAZ same type, imagine Item is imported elsewhere

Comment: So is it this: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChkHLAAmAXMiAK4YBG0+hkAHmOQM5hSgDmDBwmNgH5y6CBgDaAXVwBfXLgQB7EB2QYAnmIyjM05AF5kEvISJlkARgA0fZM1bIA5AAsIAG3dKntswPFs5CZ2fhY2IYwQLOROAO5KUO7ETnay1jgR-BYATL5mkdHOIBAcEMl5+USCQaaV+STkAMzpmfkOMTCUUGBuUD6tftXGtXV1DcgALBWjbVGOTnBs6pQILsiLyBpKlMixcOApM4SyMqMnqTInQA) or what ij7 suggests with `extends`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what [`extends`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#extending-types) is made for:

```
interface Items extends Item {
    items: Item[]
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChkHLAAmAXMiAK4YBG0+hkAHmOQM5hSgDmuAvrlyhIsRCnQQMbZBBYQQxaRKx5CRTG3LKA2gF1+ghAHsQHZBgCeyrRr3IAvMm2rCJcgEYANAwLNWyAHIACwgAG1CjAO81YA1yZx81IjJkL0S1P3IAgHcjKFDiAMS+fRKgA)